# Can you pass an array of item IDs to a Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have a normalized redux state shape and I need to render a list of items from state.

I would prefer to pass the array of item IDs to the parent component and pass each item ID to the child `ListItem` which would be connected to the store and retrieve its own item object.

That way I could avoid expensive mapState calls in the parent component that would trigger a rerender for all child `ListItem`
Components.

Is this possible with a react native Flatlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely possible. Here's a quick sketch:

```
function ListItem({item}) {
  return (...);
}
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  // look up item from state using ownProps.id e.g. if `state` maps ids to objects
  const item = state[ownProps.id];
  return {
    item,
  };
}
const ConnectedListItem = connect(mapStateToProps)(ListItem);

function List({itemIds}) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={itemIds}
      renderItem={({item}) => <ConnectedListItem id={item} />}
      ...
    />
}

// example: <List itemIds=[1, 2, 3] />
```

However if you're just worried about re-renders and performance why not make the `ListItem` component a pure component so only the affected child `ListItem`s re-render when data changes? The `connect` function from react-redux is just treating the connected `ListItem` as a pure component in order to skip re-renders.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply! I’m not super familiar with pure components but I am trying to learn more. Would you mind explaining a little more how they work? Aren’t Flatlist components pure components?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, `FlatList` itself is a pure component, but let's say one of the items in your `data` list changes and the others remain the same - the `FlatList` will need to re-render (since the `data` prop has changed) but each individual `ListItem` component should not need to, only the one that changed. By marking the `ListItem` component as pure, react will only re-render it when props change. You can either extend `PureComponent` instead of `Component` or use `React.memo` for function-based components to enable the optimization.